# Jquery avgrund plugin run with one click

Tags: jquery, avgrund

I would like to run avgrund plugin if current user is a visitor else I'd like tor run a different piece of code.

My code looks like this so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/avgrund.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" id="reply1" class="replyButton">
            <span>reply</span>
        </a>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.avgrund/1.3.3/jquery.avgrund.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(function() {

             var username = "Visitor";

             $(".replyButton").on('click', function(e) {

                 if (typeof username !== 'undefined') {

                     if (username !== 'Visitor') {
                         console.log("Do some stuff");
                     }
                     else {

                         var selectedButton = $(this).attr('id');
                         selectedButton = '#' + selectedButton;
                         $(selectedButton).avgrund();
                     }
                 }

             });


         });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is popup opens after two clicks. How should I make the code run on first click.

Here is the js fiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/sv1mmn6q

**Update:**

I tried this method which seems to work fine for this small example.

```
$(document).avgrund({
   openOnEvent: true
 });
```

Updated jsfiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/sv1mmn6q/1/

But in fact makes avgrund plugin to activate on click events. For example if you click home page it activates avgrund plugin. Which is the unintended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting these options it seems to work fine.

```
setEvent: 'click',
openOnEvent: false,
```